# How does $e^{az}$ change when $z$ is shifted $2i\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to evaluate an real-valued integral using residue theory, and the approach is to shift the fraction
$\displaystyle\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}$ from the real line up $2i\pi$ in the complex plane and evaluate in a line parallel to the $x$-axis (to create a rectangle). Now $e^x$ does not change (rigth?) it still only takes real values, but what happens to $e^{ax}$.

Here $0<a<1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess Your title should be something like "How does $e^{az}$ change when $z$ is shifted $2iπ$?"

Comment: No it's an real-valued integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$ that I want to integrate using residue theory.

Comment: That is what i am saying... may be you should then say "How does $e^{ax}$ change when $x$ is shifted $2iπ$?".. while changing from  integral on $(-\infty,\infty)$ we change $x$ to $z$ and $z$ to $\theta$...